# How to disable maven property for a project?

Tags: java, maven, selenium

When ever I'm importing a project to sping tool, project coming as maven project automatically. However I'm disabling maven property by right click on project folder.

My question:

1. How to disable maven permanently for a project?
2. Is there anyway to find out a project is maven project or not before importing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: All about pom.xml. My suggestion to you, please read maven docs.